# Nginx ignore trailing slash and do not redirect if it is missing

Tags: nginx, redirect

With my current configuration the following URL triggers redirects which are really bad for SEO.

http://localhost/blog  redirects to -> http://localhost/blog/

Here is my conf.d/default.conf file

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name localhost;
  server_name_in_redirect on;

  location / {
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    expires 1y;
    root /work/front-page/dist/browser;
  }

}
```

I would like both location to give status 200, or at least to reverse the redirect

http://localhost/blog/ redirects to -> http://localhost/blog

EDIT:
putting

```
try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
```

seems to resolve the issue, thanks @Richard Smith

Here is the full working configuration, I tested it with http -> https redirect too.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name localhost;
  server_name_in_redirect on;

  location / {
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    expires 1y;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
    root /work/front-page/dist/browser;
  }

}
```

Comment: This is default behaviour. To change the default behaviour, you could use a `try_files` directive within the `location` block. For example: `try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;`

Comment: Thanks! I tried this before but I was putting it in the server configuration not the location